# Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established in node js

Tags: node.js, ssl, tls1.2

I got this bugs
Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
Can anyone solve this issues

```
`var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': 'https://api-pesonetmbs.pchc.com.ph/api/v2/heartbeat',
    'headers': {
        'api-key': apikey,
        'signature': signature,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'requestCert': true, 
    'rejectUnauthorized': true,
    'key': fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/Certs/key.pem'), 
    'cert': fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/Certs/ServerCert.pem'), 
    'ca': fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/Certs/caServerCert.pem'), 
    'passphrase': 'pQWaI6057vd1',
    'timeout': 30000
    };
    request(options, function (error, response) {
 console.log(response);
    if (error) {
        console.log("No Response from PCHC.")
        res.send('No Response from PCHC')`your text`
   
       
    }else{
        console.log("PCHC response - " + JSON.stringify(response.body));
        res.send(response.body).status(response.statusCode);
       
      
    }
   });`
```

Comment: did you managed to find a solution? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your method can't connect to the specified endpoint - could be due to proxy or firewall settings. Check that your `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables are properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me, and the root cause was that I've set a proxy-server host as `url`. 
The solution was to provide the host as `ip address:port`

#### not working

```js
http://your_host.com/
```

#### Working perfectly

```js
http://192.168.1XX.XX:8080/
```